Firebase-admin dependency farmhash-modern throws webassembly error
I'm trying to configure firebase-admin SDK on my nextjs + TS project. Whenever i try to invoke any SDK function, i get a webAssembly error. In my case, i am trying to configure a middleware for the server side api, and when i call the verifyIdToken method it throws the error. Has anyone faced similar errors ? How can i fix this ?
Below is my middleware.ts file:
import { auth } from "./lib/config/firebaseConfig";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

interface ExtendedNextRequest extends NextRequest {
  uid?: string;
}

export async function middleware(req: ExtendedNextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  try {
    let token = req.headers.get("Authorization");
    if (!token)
      return NextResponse.json({ message: "Access Denied" }, { status: 403 });
    if (token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      token = token.split(" ")[1];
    }

    let decodedToken = await auth.verifyIdToken(token);
    let uid = decodedToken.uid;
    req.uid = uid;

    return NextResponse.next();
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error.errorInfo);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Invalid Token" }, { status: 401 });
  }
}


Below is the error i recieve:
⨯ ./node_modules/farmhash-modern/bin/bundler/farmhash_modern_bg.wasm
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
The module seem to be a WebAssembly module, but module is not flagged as WebAssembly module for webpack.
BREAKING CHANGE: Since webpack 5 WebAssembly is not enabled by default and flagged as experimental feature.
You need to enable one of the WebAssembly experiments via 'experiments.asyncWebAssembly: true' (based on async modules) or 'experiments.syncWebAssembly: true' (like webpack 4, deprecated).
For files that transpile to WebAssembly, make sure to set the module type in the 'module.rules' section of the config (e. g. 'type: "webassembly/async"').
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/farmhash-modern/bin/bundler/farmhash_modern_bg.wasm
./node_modules/farmhash-modern/bin/bundler/farmhash_modern.js
./node_modules/farmhash-modern/lib/browser.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/remote-config/condition-evaluator-internal.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/remote-config/remote-config.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
./lib/config/firebaseConfig.ts


I see the same issue...and seems to be due to a recent change in firebase-admin-node. As of 3 weeks ago they were still asking for feedback https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/2552#issuecomment-2181439126

I have the same problem. I tried downgrading to 12.0.0 like some say but I did not work for me.

@Tajs I also tried downgrading, still didn't work. The issue is open on their GitHub repo, I'm awaiting any fix or whatsoever from their team.

I have not managed to find the cause of the problem, but it seems that calling admin functions inside the middleware is buggy. A quick workaround is to create an API endpoint that returns the uid of the user connected with a session. Then you can call the endpoint inside the middleware to get the uid.

This fails because middleware.ts is executed by Vercel as an edge function, which is not a full Node environment. One solution would be to move your authentication calls out of the middleware and instead authenticate the user at the beginning of a standard serverless function.
There's more discussion over at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/2627. A library that tries to solve this issue is https://github.com/awinogrodzki/next-firebase-auth-edge but I haven't tested it myself.
