How do i use Firebase-admin auth on my nextjs application so i can verify tokens?
 ⨯ ./node_modules/farmhash-modern/bin/bundler/farmhash_modern_bg.wasm
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
The module seem to be a WebAssembly module, but module is not flagged as WebAssembly module for webpack.
BREAKING CHANGE: Since webpack 5 WebAssembly is not enabled by default and flagged as experimental feature.
You need to enable one of the WebAssembly experiments via 'experiments.asyncWebAssembly: true' (based on async modules) or 'experiments.syncWebAssembly: true' (like webpack 4, deprecated).
For files that transpile to WebAssembly, make sure to set the module type in the 'module.rules' section of the config (e. g. 'type: "webassembly/async"').
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/farmhash-modern/bin/bundler/farmhash_modern_bg.wasm
./node_modules/farmhash-modern/bin/bundler/farmhash_modern.js
./node_modules/farmhash-modern/lib/browser.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/remote-config/condition-evaluator-internal.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/remote-config/remote-config.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
./src/lib/firebase-admin.ts
 ✓ Compiled /_error in 778ms (665 modules)
 GET /_next/static/webpack/3088192808e0e46b.webpack.hot-update.json 500 in 3518ms
 GET /dashboard 404 in 2ms
 ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
 GET /dashboard 404 in 1ms
 GET /favicon.ico 500 in 9ms

import { app, initializeApp } from "firebase-admin";
import { App, cert, ServiceAccount } from "firebase-admin/app"

const adminJSon = process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_JSON
if (!adminJSon) {
    throw new Error("FIREBASE_ADMIN_JSON is not set")
}

const initAdmin = () => {
    const adminClient = initializeApp({
        credential: cert(JSON.parse(adminJSon) as ServiceAccount),
    });
    return adminClient
}

const adminGlobalThis = globalThis as unknown as {
    adminClient: ReturnType<typeof initAdmin> | undefined
}

export const adminClient = adminGlobalThis.adminClient ?? initAdmin()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") adminGlobalThis.adminClient = adminClient




when i use this on the client and on the server it gives me and error saying it needs some web assembly file
I tried uninstalling my node modules and installing it again, using the Nextjs middleware

This is a known issue when using firebase-admin in some edge runtimes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78729243/firebase-admin-dependency-farmhash-modern-throws-webassembly-error
